# How to filter and aggregate Excel data in new tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one table filled with customer data. Some examples:

- date of last contact
- gender
- ...

Now I want to create a new table where only male customers are shown, ordered by the date of the last contact.

Is there a build in function to achieve data aggregation in this way or do I have to write a script? It occurs to me that there has to be some built-in way because I think it's a common task to evaluate data in this way.

Comment: So far I discovered that i can convert my range into a Table and filter/sort. But that only allows me to create one Table and not multiple (maybe a dashboard) with different kind of sortings/filters

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table? Could you be more clear in what you're trying to do? I understand you want to use data you have and examine it based on multiple attributes. A pivot table will do that.

Comment: No I havn't used pivot tables so far. I am quite new to Excel, I've used it occasionally for easy tasks but never took a dive into all the possibilities. I will give pivot tables a try!

Comment: If pivot tables work you can `copy -> paste special -> values` to new sheets or you can use the camera tool to take screen shots of the tables. Also, if they work for you come back and let me know so I can "answer" the question properly

Comment: Look at advanced filters as well. You can create macros to pull what you need into different sections based on criteria and uniqueness etc

Answer (score 1):

Look at using Advanced Filter. You can either filter in place, or set rather elaborate critera and Filter to a new location.

It is really quick and you can setup your data range so that if it is refreshed from an external source you can easily pull a new table to view.

You can also set your criteria fields with your most common choices using data validation lists or dropdowns and have a fairly extensive report generator.

Comment: advanced filters look interesting, but i don't know if they do the trick. this is the excact thing i want to do: i have a table with costumer data:  name | date | ... it is setup as a table and new records will be added. now i want another table just showing the name and date. filtered by dates (should be in the future). i could filter my first table, but thats not what i want to do. so how do i link the two tables, thats all i need basically

Comment: That is exactly what advanced filter is good for. Your original table is treated like a datasource, you setup criteria, and you can have the results write to a new table location filtered as you wish.